# Create a parent activity instead of continuing when a child activity is finished

Tags: android

Is that possible that a parent activity is recreated instead of continuation when its child activity is finished (it was destroyed by "back" key)..

A problem is the following:
I use CameraX in activity A (parent) and B (child).
When I return from the activity B into A I try bind CameraX but it happens before B is totally destroyed and camera doesn't launch.
I tried to find out the moment when B is destroyed is A but didn't find anything for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by clearing the back stack at both activities by attaching [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) and [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) flags to the intent.

Assuming that the original activity is `Activity1`, and the second activity is `Activit2`.

Then the code at `Activity1` whenever you want to start `Activity2` will be:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

And when you press the back button at Activity2, start over Activity1 by overriding `onBackPrssed()`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity2.this, Activity1.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```